# Regex finding and printing multilpe matches inside a single match

Tags: python, regex, match

My problem is say I have `ab+` and I input `aabbbbba` it only finds one match when theres `ab`, `abb`, `abbb`, `abbbb`, `abbbbb`.

My code finds the match at index 1 but doesn't consider the matches inside and I have tried everything to try and get it to print down from `abbbbb` to `ab`.
Here is my code:

```
import re
exp, srt = input("RegEx,String:").split()
print(srt)
for m in re.finditer(exp, srt,):
   print('"', m.group(0), '"', "is found at index: ", m.start())
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to install the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package, a more powerful alternative to `re`. It supports variable-width lookbehind assertions (while the `re` package only supports fixed-width lookbehind assertions), so you can use the following regex instead:

```
regex.findall(r'(?<=(ab+))', 'aabbbbba')
```

This returns:

```
['ab', 'abb', 'abbb', 'abbbb', 'abbbbb']
```